# witharrows package aligning equation to the left

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, align, flalign, witharrows

I'm using `witharrows` package to document my steps in solving an equation like so:

```latex
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item
    \begin{flalign*}
    \begin{WithArrows}[format=l, jot=4pt]
    \sin^2x &= 3 \cdot \cos^2x \Arrow[]{$\div \cos^2x$} &\\[4pt]
    \frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x} &= 3
    \end{WithArrows}
    \end{flalign*}
    \end{enumerate}
```

I wish for the equation to be aligned to the left so I set an anchor point in the end as-well `&`.

The result is centered and the arrows are overlapping the equations and I'm not sure why:
[image]

I get the following errors:

```
Package witharrows Error: You should use the command \Arrow only in the last(witharrows) {WithArrows}. ^^I\end{flalign*}
Package witharrows Error: Your environment {WithArrows} has 1 columns and
```

Which I cannot understand.
Would appreciate help deciphering what it means and how to solver it.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
full example:
https://pastebin.com/hshSaUra

Comment: You should put a complete compilable code (with the `\documentclass`, the `\begin{document}`, the `\end{document}`, etc.).

Comment: @F.Pantigny I've added the full code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{witharrows}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item
$\begin{WithArrows}[format=l, jot=4pt]
\sin^2x = 3 \cdot \cos^2x \Arrow[]{$\div \cos^2x$} \\[4pt]
\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x} = 3
\end{WithArrows}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Then the equation is just centered and not aligned to the left next to `(a)`

Comment: Actually I missed the part where you wrapped the whole environment with `$` inline math expression, and that actually solved it. Can you explain why you did that?

Comment: The environment `{WithArrows}` is similar to the environment `{aligned}` of `amsmath` (and `mathtools`): it is composed in its own box, can be inserted in other environment, and must be composed in math mode. On the other side, the environment `{DispWithArrows}` is similar to `{align}` (which is *not* `{aligned}`): it takes the full width of the page (or current column) and must *not* be composed in math mode.

Comment: Why not use `\dfrac` for the last line?

Comment: @Bernard: You are right. It would probably be better here to use the key 'displaystyle‘.

Comment: Or at least `\mfrac`.

Comment: @Bernard I'm new to LaTex, I see `dfrac` changes the size of the font of the fraction, so I'm not really sure when one should use `dfrac`, `mfrac`, `cfrac` or `frac`, just that if you have fraction inside fraction you better use something other than `frac` for the inner fractions and maybe fake height with `\vphantom` if you have problems with your nominator getting close to the fraction line.

Comment: @Jorayen: \dfrac forces display style fraction in cases when the default would be text style ((e.g. in an array, a matrix of the cases environments), and it may introduce a great size discrepancy w.r.t. the rest of a formula. Of course, it's a matter of appreciation, but I think that \mfrac (~80% of displaystyle) is often a good compromise.

Comment: @Bernard where can I read about display style vs text style?

Comment: @Jorayen: There's not much to say: compare the result of  \frac{…}{…} in a displayed equation and in an online formula . The `dfrac`, `\cfrac` and `tfrac` commands are introduced by  amsmath, are are explained in detail in `amsldoc.pdf`, which is a part of the documentation of the package. As to  `mfrac` (medium-sized fractions) it id defined, along with other medium-size commands and environment by the `nccmath` package; you can read details and examples in its documentation.